# Objective-C use typedef enum to set Class behavior, like Cocoa

Tags: iphone, uikit, enums, uibutton, typedef

Im extending the UIButton Class to be able to set the font and color of the UINavigationBarButton ( from this code example: [switch on the code](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/iphone-tutorial-how-to-create-a-blue-navigation-button) )

I goes like this:

```
@interface NavBarButtonGrey : UIButton 
-(id)init;

@end


@implementation NavBarButtonGrey

-(id)init {
if(self = [super init]) {
    self.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 49.0, 30.0);
    self.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentCenter;
    self.contentHorizontalAlignment = UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentCenter;

    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"greyNavButton.png"];
    UIImage *stretchImage = 
    [image stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:15.0 topCapHeight:0.0];
    [self setBackgroundImage:stretchImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    self.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    [self setTitleShadowColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    self.titleShadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, -1);
    self.titleLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:13];
}

return self;
}
@end
```

This is ok, but of course not very flexible.
How do I incorporate using a typedef enum (like Apple does) for all the different
colors, fonts and sizes I would like my custom button to conform to.

The only thing I can get out of the interface files from UIKit is that it is done like this:

```
typedef enum {
RGCustomNavBarButtonStyleBlue,
RGCustomNavBarButtonStyleGrey,
RGCustomNavBarButtonStyleBlack,
RGCustomNavBarButtonStyleGreen,
RGCustomNavBarButtonStyleRed, 
} RGCustomNavBarButtonStyle;
```

How to get from that and into a working implementation that takes font, size, color etc. from the values of the enum through the constructor(initWithStyle)?

Does one overload constructors in Objective C? multiple constructors?

Hope it makes sense and thank you for any help given:)

Comment: To start, UINavigationBarButton doesn't exist. You probably meant UIBarButtonItem, which inherits from UIBarItem, which in turn inherits from NSObject. Subclassing UIButton isn't going to help you in this respect.

Comment: Sorry I meant UIButton:)
I do it like this:
 NavBarButtonGrey *addButton = [[NavBarButtonGrey alloc] init];
 [addButton setTitle:@"Add" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
 [addButton addTarget:self action:@selector(addStuff) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
 
 UIBarButtonItem *addNavButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:addButton];
 self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = addNavButton;

With my custom NavBarButtonGrey and it works just fine? I couldn't find a way to tint the UIBarButtonIten so I decided to try and do a custom one that could be customized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have multiple constructors such as;

```
-(MyClass) initWithFont: (UIFont) font;
-(MyClass) initWithFonmt: (UIFont) font andColor: (UIColor) color;
```

etc.

Then call [super init] as the first line in each of your custom constructors.

Comment: Thanks:)
That looks like it. So I could go -(MyClass) initWithFont: (RGCustomNavBarButtonStyle) font; and pass it "RGCustomNavBarButtonStyleGreen" as the font because Im essentially making my own type with typedef. And then have a switch case inside the Class that defined the parameters before returning a button of type UIButton.
Great:) Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

To expand on what ennuikiller said above, I was taught (Hillegass's book) to pick one initializer—usually the one with the most options, like your initWithFont:andColor:—and have the other initializers call it. That main initializer is referred to as the designated initializer.

So your code would have a fully-implemented initWithFont:andColor: that calls [super init], and then you'd also have an initWithFont: that looks something like this:

```
-(MyClass) initWithFont: (UIFont) font
{
    [self initWithFont:font andColor:RGCustomNavBarButtonStyleBlack];
}
```

Then your initWithFont:andColor: would handle all the other setup and calling [super init].

Comment: Hi Jay. Thank you for elaborating on the initializer subject. The question is some month old by now and I have learned a few does and don't since then. I too read that this was the preferred approach in an Objective C book. I find my self using the typedef enum/multiple initializers approach more and more, the naming conventions in Objective C are wonderful. In what other language is names like this encouraged: shouldRemoveViewContainingRedBackgroundFromSuperView :)